# deploying SSH keys to servers

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys

I have the following playbook:

```
---
 - name: provision toms keys
    hosts: ssh4.demo.com
    tasks:
     - name: ensure user tom is present
       user: name=tom state=present

     - name: ensure private key and public one are present
       copy: src=ssh_keys/tom dest=/.ssh mode=0600
       with_items:
         - id_rsa.pub
         - id_rsa

 - name: provision toms public keys
    hosts: ssh1.demo.com

    sudo: yes

    tasks:

     - user: name=tom comment="Add tom" group=staff

     - name: Placing key
       authorized_key: user=tom key="{{ lookup('file', 'ssh_keys/tom/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

I have a local directory that contains both my ssh public and private keys like this:

```
./ssh_keys
./ssh_keys/david
./ssh_keys/david/id_rsa
./ssh_keys/david/id_rsa.pub
./ssh_keys/fred
./ssh_keys/fred/id_rsa
./ssh_keys/fred/id_rsa.pub
./ssh_keys/joe
./ssh_keys/joe/id_rsa
./ssh_keys/joe/id_rsa.pub
./ssh_keys/paul
./ssh_keys/paul/id_rsa
./ssh_keys/paul/id_rsa.pub
./ssh_keys/peter
./ssh_keys/peter/id_rsa
./ssh_keys/peter/id_rsa.pub
./ssh_keys/tom
./ssh_keys/tom/id_rsa
./ssh_keys/tom/id_rsa.pub
```

I need to create some playbooks that can be used to push the keys to various hosts defined in the hosts fields.

However, the .ssh key directories are getting created incorrectly. i.e. a directory called tom gets created below an id_rsa and id_rsa.pub directory.

e.g.

```
 /home/tom/.ssh/id_rsa/tom/id_rsa
```

Does anybody have a good example playbook for this ?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 ---
 - name: provision toms keys
    hosts: ssh4.demo.com
    tasks:
     - name: ensure user tom is present
       user: name=tom state=present

     - name: ensure private key and public one are present
       copy: src=ssh_keys/tom/ dest=/.ssh mode=0600
```

You can copy the whole directory tom or the content of tom with 'tom/'.
Also you don't need to specify the files, when you copy the complete directory.